# python filter function on a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, json, api, filter, built-in

suppose that I have following result from the api :

```
[
    {
          "id":"1234",
          "views":132624,
          "rate":"4.43",
          "url":"someurl.com",
          "added":"2022-06-14 16:27:28",
          "default_thumb":{
             "size":"medium",
             "width":640,
             "height":360,
          }
    },
    {
          "id":"1234",
          "views":132624,
          "rate":"4.43",
          "url":"someurl.com",
          "added":"2022-06-14 16:27:28",
          "default_thumb":{
             "size":"medium",
             "width":640,
             "height":360,
          }
    },
    ...
]
```

and I just want to fetch urls in dictionaries, to do that I tried to filter the list with python `filter()` function :

```
fetched_urls = list(filter(lambda video_data: video_data['url'] , videos_data))
```

but when I print `fetched_urls` I'll get all of the array without any filter process, is there any way to achieve this filtered array using `filter()` function ?

Comment: `filter` function is used to filter only those items in the list (or iterable) which returns `True` for the given function. So, from lambda function you are returning a tuple (url, videos_data), which is a truthy value. That why its returning exact same array.

Comment: you can use  either a simple for loop, or  `map()` function or list comprehension to do this.

Comment: @SandeepRawat thank you I got my misunderstanding <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `map` instead of `filter`

Answer (score 0):

filter returns the items if the condition is met. try this:

```
[a['url'] for a in video_data if 'url' in a]
```